# Migrate from Office 365 to On-Premises

Tags: exchange-2010, migration, microsoft-office-365

What are the steps to perform to migrate from Office365 to an On-Premises installation?

I am aware that I can just copy/paste emails - but that is not a quite good solution for end customers.

My setup is running Exchange 2010 SP2.

Comment: Are you able to extract the entire user's mailbox to the PST?

Comment: @VickVega From what I've googled, it doesnt seem like it is possible. There are some guys who made a program that does it - but I dont want to pay for it, and I am not afraid of using powershell to do it.

Comment: I would assume if you have Outlook, which connected to the hosted Exchange using Outlook Anywhere, you should be able simply export the data from the mailbox to the PST file. I must say I never done this, so my assumption could be wrong.

Comment: @VickVega That is one way of doing it, although I dont want to do it on every user manually - there must be some automated way to do it for free.

Comment: Powershell scripting running with Admin privileges to extract data to PSTs? 

http://bit.ly/OtpL7L

Comment: @VickVega I dont think that will work for Office 365..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and most supported option would be to setup an on-site Exchange box and then setup coexistence between Office 365 and your on-premise box and then simply migrate users from the cloud mailboxes back down to your on-premise box.  Once everyone is migrated simply kill the coexistence.

Essentially reverse MSFT's instructions for setting up coexistence a bit.

This is probably the easiest AND still supported by MSFT if you have issues since it falls under the premise of coexistence.

Comment: I like the way you say: "and then simply migrate users..."
I really dont find it simple.. First I get one error, and now I get "exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation"

Comment: @FrederikNielsen Well, then no offense but if you had already tried that you should have posted it as part of your question. Can't help with stuff we don't know you have done.

Comment: You should also check out MessageOps.com they have lots of tools to help with this kind of stuff.  It's not "free" but you can get them for simply adding them as your partner of record in MSOL.

Comment: Sorry about that - I have been messing with it for a while, and this is one of the things I tried, just forgot to update my question here.

Comment: @FrederikNielsen Coexistence should work and if its not, like I said, call MSFT, its a supported thing.  If you don't want to go that route then check out MessageOps.com they have tools to download all of the mailboxes.  Coexistence will save you having to re-import all of the mail though.

Comment: Allright, i'll have a look at it. Thanks for your reply.